# Program cannot be opened because d3dx9d.dll was not found

Tags: dll, directx-9, d3dx

I'm writing a program in DirectX 9 and it can't be opened because of error

> Program cannot be opened because d3dx9d.dll was not found

So I have a few questions:

-Where can I get it? I've been searching and the only source I could find is DLL-Files.com and registration is required and I don't want to give my personal information to an untrusted source

-What are the files d3dx9d_33.dll that I found on my PC and can I use them in this situation? There's really not much information that I could find.

Comment: What version of the legacy DirectX SDK are you using to build your application? What OS are you using? The Debug versions of ``D3DX9`` are only installed by the legacy DirectX SDK, and are of the form ``d3dx9d_xx.dll``.  Be sure to see [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/directx-sdk--august-2009-). You should consider avoiding legacy Direct3D 9 entirely.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn I'm using DirectX libraries that were installed with mingw, because they have .a formats and I couldn't make use of the .lib format in the DirectX SDKs. I'm using Windows7. So how do I make use of d3dx9d_xx.dll? And is it bad to be programming in DirectX 9 now?

Comment: I have no idea what MinGW is going here, but basically it's wrong. Something wrong with just using Visual Studio Community edition instead?

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn I'm kind of used to code blocks and don't really trust VS community edition after the time they were attaching additional processes to programs to "customize experience"